Gitlab ci use compare_to for CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
[[service]]:test-branches:
      <<: *test_stage
      cache:
        key: "${{CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-${CI_JOB_STAGE}-[[service]]}"
        paths:
        - services/[[service]]/vendor/
      rules:
        - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
          changes:
            compare_to: $CI_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
            paths:
              - services/[ [ service ] ]/**/*
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
          changes:
            compare_to: 'refs/heads/master'
            paths:
              - services/[[service]]/**/*

I basically want to create a job, based on above condition, if there are any merger equest open(in my case 1 per source branch), compare the changes with the target branch.
Please note these are the push events we are using.
CI_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME is the branch we can get through curl command, but I have read somewhere the custom variables cannot be used in the conditions of variables.
Can someone suggest how I can compare the changes to target branch when event is push and check is CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
